# UCWA: integrating advanced chat options

Tags: chat, lync, instant-messaging, ucwa

I have created a simple chatting application using which two users can chat with each other. Currently i'm able to send only simple and plain text messages.
Next as an enhancement, i would like to send formatted text messages. Eg. Changing the font, text style, size, bold, italics, etc. Also i would like to integrate file sharing while chatting.

So i would like to know:

- If ucwa Api has a provision for sending and receiving formatted text
  messages?
- Is there a provision to share files as well.

Since `Microsoft Lync` provides sending and receiving formatted text, i think UCWA should also do the same.

If there is no such provision, then could anyone suggest some ideas on this? (some 3rd party libraries paid/free doesn't matter)

I have gone through some of ucwa documentation but couldn't find anything relevant.

Any suggestion shall be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If ucwa Api has a provision for sending and receiving formatted text messages?

The formatted messages you see in the Lync Client are really Html formatted messages which Ucwa also supports.  To enable the receiving of these type of messages there are two options.  The application can either include it in the request to [makeMeAvailable](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-makeMeAvailable) providing [supportedMessageFormats](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Enums-MessageFormat) or by updating the [communication](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-communication) via a Put request with the similar information.

At this point the application should be able to receive Html-formatted messages and send messages via [sendMessage](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-sendMessage) using the Content-Type text/html.

### Is there a provision to share files as well?

Currently [dataCollaboration](http://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-dataCollaboration), file-sharing, is not available.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So the solution is just to set the content type to text/html???

Comment: If you want to send an formatted message yes, if you run into problems post your request (headers/body).